# Android virtual device with Intel Atom(x86) and GPU emulation shows black boxes on Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, gpu, intel, android-virtual-device

[image]

I created an android virtual device for phonegap development, with the Intel Atom(x86) as CPU/ABI feature.

When I turn on the GPU emulation on my avd, the screen shows a black box in the middle.

This only happens with phonegap+jquerymobile. Doesn't happen in native android apps.

My laptop has a Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2350M 2.30GHz CPU, with Intel integrated graphics. I am using Linux Mint 13 Cinnamon. The virtualization on my BIOS is active too.

How can I remove the black box in there?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I fixed it already. The problem was related with some .css files on my page. The GPU emulation runs flawless with Linux.
Just be careful about the .css paths every time you have to create your own themes in phonegap.

Comment: I donot use any css and still seeing a lot of black rectangles.

Comment: @Phương Are you using JQuery Mobile in your App?
If so, you can check also the recomended basic page structure
http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/pages/
Sometimes it helps to start with a blank page from scratch.

Comment: I do experience it with a newly created phonegap app, with/without its css.

Comment: Any updates on this?  I'm running into the same issues.  Black boxes in azure emulator with intel hardware acceleration.  Using jquery mobile.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I'm on MAC OS X Maverick, running phonegap android intel. My index.html is very basic. No references to css files. No javascript.

I see black boxes ... everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

These look to be related posts on the phonegap github page.

https://github.com/codecomputerlove/PhotoSwipe/issues/477

Adding opacity: 0 to the folowing

```
/* UILayer */
div.ps-uilayer {
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

fixes the problem.

I haven't tested this yet, but I'm about to. Note, this is working for me on windows intel with haxm acceleration, but not on mac osx intel with haxm acceleration.